# Swipe after UIView zoomed issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer, pinchzoom

I have a `UIView` with zooming enabled, and a swipe gesture recognizer setup. When the user is not zoomed, the swipes come through great, but as soon as the user zooms in, the swipe won't come through.

Is there a secret to getting the swipe after zoomed?

Comment: hey mate,just use coverflow or iCarousel with different functionality may be you find something from this or also this class is useful for your requirement... http://www.binpress.com/app/icarousel/614 and also another is http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html

Comment: Paras, iCarousel's functionality is different from my requirement. There is something happening after zoom which is creating issue in swipe or there are some properties that I have to set.

Comment: did you set contentsize of scrollview with your total page??means if you set scrolling in Horizontal then you set the contentsize of scrollview??

Comment: can you post some code of scrollview Properties which you define in your view??

Comment: Paras I am doing swipe on UIView, not on UIScrollView.

Comment: ok now see this http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/gestures/swipe-gesture-for-ios-apps/

Comment: Paras I think you are not getting me. Swiping is working fine when UIView is not zoomed. After zoomed we need swipe hard to make it work.
Gesture recognizer not recognizing the each swipe on UIView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17375/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-nikhil)

Comment: Sorry Paras, Web chat is restricted in my organization.

Comment: ohh ok mate but i post my code in chatbox ,now i just try to solve your problem ok bro.. :)